# How to update an existing testcase using the Kiwi TCMS API

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I'm unable to find reference to a method that allows updating the summary or text of an existing case. I see nothing under system.listmethods that allows updating them. How is this achieved ?
Thanks.

Unfortunately I've found nothing in the documentation that suggests this is possible.